# Rails: activerecord update to new association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, has-many

I have two models: User and Role. One user can have many roles.

Suppose user1 have role1 and role2. Now I want user1 to have role2 and role3.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

This is my code

```
user = User.find(1) 
newrole = Role.find(2) #get role3 

user.roles[0] = newrole 

user.roles[0].save  # does not work 

user.save # does not work
```

What is the correct way in ruby on rails to solve my problem?

Comment: `user.roles.new = "newrole"` and `user.roles.save`

Comment: I want to update role1 -> role3, not adding a new role

Comment: whats your column name for role in roles model?

Comment: I find it much easier to work with ids if they are known `user.role_ids = [2, 3]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than updating the record from `role1` to `role3`, a simpler way is to delete the record for `role1` and create new for `role2`.

For `has_and_belongs_to_many`, all you would need is passing the ids and rails would handle it automatically.

**Example:**

*For Rails Console:*

```
-> @user = User.first
-> puts @user.role_ids
   # [1,2]

-> @user.role_ids = [2, 3]
```

This would assign the new roles to the user by deleting the `role1` and creating record for `role3`

*edit.html.erb (View)*:

Lets assume you have a form for `User` and have a dropdown for `roles` with multiple selection

```
<%= form_for(book) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :first_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :roles %>
    <%= f.collection_select :role_ids, Role.all, :id, :name, {}, {:multiple => true} %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

*users_controller.rb (Controller)*:

```
def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.update(user_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render :edit }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

private

def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, role_ids: [])
end
```

Now when you select `role2` and `role3`, and submit the form, Rails would handle it simply by deleting the record for `role1` and create another for `role3`

Answer (score 1):

```
user.roles.destroy(Role.find(1)) # assuming Role.find(1) == role1
user.roles << Role.find(3) # assuming Role.find(3) == role3
```